# How to setup a TAGS file (etags) for multiple git projects?

Tags: git, etag, exuberant-ctags

When setting up emacs for a git project, I am using

```
git ls-files | xargs -d\\n etags
```

which creates a TAGS file in the current directory. I often want to include symbols from another project, so I append them with absolute path:

```
etags -a /path/to/project/*.[ch]
```

However, when I have two *git* repositories

```
git ls-files /path/to/git_project
```

will not work: git tells me that the path is outside the current repository. I could cd into it, but then the paths printed on stdout are not relative to the TAGS file, so emacs will not find them.

Is there any elegant way to solve this problem? All that comes into my mind is some overcomplicated shell script magic to prepend the prefix to each line before feeding into xargs...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm not an emacs user. I'll tell you how I'd do this in vim so that maybe you can get an idea of the equivalent solution for emacs:

```
:set tags=/path/to/project1/tags,/path/to/project2/tags
:set path=/path/to/project1,/path/to/project2
```

Those two settings allow me to jump to the tags found in both projects.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but I don't think emacs supports loading multiple tag files(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
{ git ls-files; git --git-dir=/path/to/the/other/project\'s/.git ls-files; } \
| xargs -d\\n etags
```

If you want append the relative path to the front of the names, just do that:

```
{ git ls-files
  git --git-dir=path/to/other/.git ls-files | sed s,^,path/to/other,
} | xargs -d\\n etags
```

Comment: Interesting, but it has the same effect as cd'ing into the directory - the files are listed relative to the directory, but I need them relative to the TAGS file (or with absolute path).